# Print correct variable name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm trying to log variable name in JavaScript with its value using a function with the following code...

```js
var x = 5;
function get(v) {
    console.log(Object.keys({v})[0] + " = " + v);
}
get(x); // It should log "x = 5"
```

But instead, it logs `v = 5`.

Is there a way to store the variable name, and to log the variable name correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because at the time you print, you are constructing an object which has a key named "v"... that is what `{v}` does.

You can solve this by creating the object at the moment that you have access to the `x` variable, and do  `{x}`:

```js
var x = 5;
function get(v) {
    console.log(Object.entries(v)[0].join(" = "));
}
get({x});
```